# Getting two divs to share one background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to get two individual divs which are close in proximity to share one background image but I'm not sure if this is possible. I've uploaded two pictures, the second being designed for a smaller screen (just to further explain what I mean) https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsdZh.jpg . I can't imagine two separate background images would work as they wouldn't line up when resizing the window.

The only solution I can think of is creating two plain white divs to overlay on one single div but that seems like a dodgy way to go about it. I'm not expecting a hunk of code to be written for me, maybe just explain if it's possible and a reference so I can learn. Cheers.

Comment: The solution to your problem is actually simple, and lies in the `background-position` of the images.  Set the background image to be the same, but set the `background-position` to be different depending on which part you want to display.

Comment: @cale_b please post your answer as an answer, not as a comment..

Comment: Another 'solution' is to wrap both divs in another div and give this wrapper div the background image.

Comment: @JoaquínO - I won't.  Two reasons: 1. There's not quite enough info in the question to do a good job.  2. It's simple enough that I'd rather let someone else who is interested in earning the rep do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys :) ... I'll also play around with your suggestion jeff.

Comment: @jeff Is there any way you could show me an example on how to do this? I do like there answers but I do feel like yours would achieve a better result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on @cale_b's comment, you can set the same background to both `div`'s and then use the `background-position` property to do the delusion of *background sharing*.

Then you can use media queries to make it look good in mobile too.

Here you've got a simple example that looks like the one you posted:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#top {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-image: url("https://placekitten.com/800/400");
  background-position: 0 0;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-indent: 50px;
}

#bottom {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("https://placekitten.com/800/400");
  background-position: 0 -220px;
}

#bottom ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#bottom ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="top">
    I'm a banner
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    <ul>
      <li>I'm</li>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>menu</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

As I understand, you want to use only one image copy of one image over two `div` and you dont want to use any *overlay*.

So you can do the following: 
On the **bottom** `div`, use `background-position-y:-100px` *or any other desired* value. This way you push the image upwards.

This looks promising so far, but you will face an issue with the size of the background size specially if you are making a *responsive* web page. 
I would say that `background-size:100% 100%`for both `div` would do the job yet it will make the image stretching (unless you go really **responsive**).

I still recommend using an overlay or even a ready made image. But if you insist on using two `div` then the above steps should be enough while you have to make your design suitable for this image.

N.B. keep in mind that you might need to use `background-repeat:no-repeat`

Comment: Thanks for the input :)